# Android Searching Database with Empty Where Clause

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to do a search function in android that will allow the user search with different filters. I am able to create a simple `select` statement with multiple `where` clauses. My issue arises when the user doesnt use the filter options, is there a way to continue the select statement but use blank values in the `where` clause?

For example, the user will want to search for all the cars and add a filter looking for specific green cars made in the year 2011.

```
"Select * from cars where colour = 'green' AND year = 2011"
```

Example where the user searches without filters for all cars

```
"Select * from cars where colour = '' AND year = "
```

I dont want to have to use two statements I would just like to use the one and have blanks in the `where` clause is nothing is selected in the filter, is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with a simple method, for example:

```
public void searchMethod(boolean filtered, colourString, yearValue) {

     String selectQuery = "";

     if (filtered)
         selectQuery = "Select * from cars where colour = " + colourString + " AND year = " + yearValue;
     else
         selectQuery = "Select * from cars";

     Cursor c = mDb.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks i will try this out

Answer (score 0):

u can write somelogic like this:-

> String whereClause = "WHERE colour = 'green' AND year = 2011';
>
> String query = "SELECT * FROM cars ";
>
> if(isForFilter) { //booelan to check if result is based on filter
>
> query = query + whereClause;
>
> }